# highest frequency at which an ANSI C routine can run on an embedded system

Tags: embedded

Which of the following correctly identify the highest frequency at which an ANSI C routine can run on an embedded system if its execution time is 18 miliseconds

```
A 18 HZ
B 55 HZ
C 18 KHZ
D 0.055 HZ
E 55KHZ
```

Comment: The answer is number milliseconds per second divide by execution time.

Comment: Probably my problem is my bad english but the question is weird for me. What is the relationship between execution of a routine and the maximum frequency of and embedded system? I mean execution time depends form the routine budy and the system frequency... And what's the matter of ANSI C here?

Comment: ANSI C, embedded system, and the CPU clock frequency are all irrelevant.  The basic question is, if something has a period of 18 milliseconds, then what is the maximum frequency at which that something can occur?

Comment: That an arithmetic problem, not a programming question (1 / 0.018 = 55.55556).  The "ANSI C" and "embedded system" constraints are entirely irrelevant - that is the highest frequency *any* routine that takes 18ms can be executed on *any* system, or indeed the highest frequency that *anything* that takes 18ms can be performed by *any* means.

Comment: Sounds like a poor homework question set by a poor tutor.

Comment: Well, it's a physics question... what's the relation between time and frequency? _t = 1 / f_.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the relationship between execution of a routine and the maximum frequency of and embedded system?

The assumption here is that this program is the only piece of software that is running on the embedded system.

```
int main(void)
{
   ....
   while(1)
   {
      ansi_c_function()
   }
}
```

If the function takes 18 ms, what is the frequency of calling this function?

The answer is 1/18ms i.e. 55 hz

Comment: The question is **_highest frequency_**. You answered to the a question like: what is the output frequency of a function that takes 18ms of execution to output something?